# Finding path to plist in Xcode project folder

Tags: objective-c, xcode, plist, writetofile

I have a plist in my Xcode project's resource folder but on physical drive it's in the top folder of my project. I want to read and write from this same file. Using NSBundle reads it properly and gives no problem. I'm using this code to read file path:

```
NSString *thePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]  pathForResource:@"MyFile" ofType:@"plist"];
```

but i think NSBundle doesn't allow writing back and so it didn't work when i tried to write back the file. Using the following code creates/ updates file using application path

```
NSArray *pathArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDirectory, YES);
NSString * docsDirectory = [pathArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [docsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyFile.plist"];
```

but for now, I need to write on internal file. Any solution to access it? Besides, I've tried giving path from my working directory to project directory. It also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It's not `NSBundle` that doesn't support writing, it's iOS itself.  iOS will not let your app write to its own bundle.

Comment: oh, ok. So i guess there isn't any way to trick iOS but we can write just anywhere outside the bundle?

Comment: Attempting to "trick" iOS usually results in your app being rejected from the App Store.  You can't write just anywhere outside the bundle, there are [specific directories](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW11) set aside for you to use.

Comment: NSBundle doesn't allow for writing, but you can read the plist from the bundle and write it to the documents directory and get full access from there, correct?

Comment: i did't intend to trick it for release :) i've found alternative. thanks for every information, every bit is worthwhile as i'm almost new to it.

Comment: @user25004: correct... but as Jim said it's not NSBundle that restricts, it's iOS itself.